# Scaling non-client area for per-monitor high-DPI support on application supporting Windows 8.1

Tags: winapi, windows-8.1, dpi, highdpi

I'm developing an application that runs on Windows 10 and 8.1 and have run against the problem of scaling the non-client area (menu bar, title bar) when moving between monitors with different DPI. The client area is handled but the non-client area goes out of proportions. The DPI Awareness is set to PerMonitorAware (v1 since v2 is not available on Windows 8.1).

The function EnableNonClientDpiScaling does exactly what I would need (it is the accepted answer to all similar questions) - alas it is only part of the API from Windows 10 on.

Is there a way to manually handle this without the before mentioned function - in order to keep support for Windows 8.1? Or does supporting Windows 8.1 means it's not possible to resize the non-client area when moving between screens with different DPI?

Comment: Is it worth supporting 8.1? Surely most people would have taken advantage of the free upgrade to 10.

Comment: @JonathanPotter You mean downgrade? On a small tablet, 8.1 is better than 10.

Comment: Non-client area per monitor scaling introduced in Windows 10 Aniversary Update [High-DPI Scaling Improvements](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/).

Comment: _Scaling of non-client area. Prior to the Anniversary Update there was no way to have the Windows-drawn non-client area DPI scale (caption bar, system menus, top-level scroll bars, menu bars, etc.). This meant that if you created a per-monitor application you’d be left with incorrectly sized (too big or too small) non-client area after the DPI change without any recourse other than drawing all that stuff yourself. In the Anniversary Update we added an API that you could call to turn on non-client scaling, EnableNonClientDpiScaling but now with PMv2 you get this automatically_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DPI support is a moving target, you just have to decide what your minimum supported platform is and accept that multi-monitor scaling will not be perfect on these older platforms.

Call `EnableNonClientDpiScaling` on the versions where it is available (`GetProcAddress` or the equivalent in whatever you language you are using).

The way the new awareness manifest element works in Windows 10 means that you can be Per-Monitor v2 where it is supported (1703 and later) and either PMv1, System or Unaware on older builds. PMv2 gives you automatic scaling of `DialogBox` based dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Anders, `GetProcAddress` was just the thing I was looking for. Although it does not solve non-client area resizing on Win 8.1 (it seems there really is no way apart from drawing everything oneself), it makes possible setting the latest `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` on Win 10:

```
// the following sets PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 on Win10 and
// reverts to PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_AWARE on Win 8.1

typedef BOOL(__stdcall *SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext)(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT);
SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext dpi_call = nullptr;
dpi_call = reinterpret_cast<SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext>(GetProcAddress(
    GetModuleHandle(TEXT("User32.dll")),
    "SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext"));
if (dpi_call != nullptr) {
    if (!(*dpi_call)((DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT) - 4))
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to set DPI aware app.");
} else {
    if (SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE) != S_OK)
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to set DPI aware app.");
}
```

Comment: You don't need this code, it can be set with the manifest. "True/PM" for the Vista element and Per Monitor v2 for the Windows 10 element.